# What are the consequences of an unrelated plural domain name?

Tags: seo, domains

Let's say that my domain is `website.com` and that there is an existing `websites.com`.

Given that the `websites.com` (in plural) domain that I don't own has very high Domain Authority and the `website.com` domain that I own have very low Domain Authority, **Is it going to be possible for my domain to rank up?**

**Do I risk getting penalized by search engines?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not get anything from it. If you consider that `www.example.com` and `example.com` are two domains according to Google, imagine two domains, from two hosters, with two different websites.

However, you *should* be carefull, because of [Typosquating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting). If you have `example.com`, while `exampleS.com` exists, and you are in a similar industry or if people can't distinguish you from them, you might get some not-so-friendly message from their lawyer. If you do this on purpose to harm them, there might even be legal issues to this.

**TLDR;** Just pick a name you like/fits you.

Answer (score 1):

The web is full of plural names (like googles.com) or the same names in other TLDs, If a popular website domain name is `example.com` then there is probably `example.net` registered amongst other alternatives (.org, .website, etc).

You won't get any more benefits from search engines than receiving visitors who wrongly typed the domain name (typos), you can't `steal` other websites *authority*, but you can have a slightly benefit from keywords being searched that match the domain. In this case the only real benefit is that users who instead of typing the popular `example.com`, they can wrongly type: `exampleS.com` and arrive to your web.

Comment: Thanks @marcanuy, Actually I was wondering if trying to "steal" websites authority would get me penalized to oblivion by search engines.

Comment: This is a well known topic, it is known as **typosquatting**, I don't think Search Engines penalize that behaviour but it can lead to legal issues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting

Answer (score 1):

The only penalty that you might incur is if you have listed duplicate content on both the websites, else there should be no issue regarding the same.